# how to dynamic head in nuxt js

Tags: vue.js, axios, seo, nuxt.js, meta

i used application by nuxt.js
how to set dynamic meta tag from api ?
in asyncData get from api but not set title in head!
not waiting get from api after set title in head:{} !

```
 async asyncData({ params, app }) {
    try {
      let post = await app.$axios.get("/api/post/post?slug=" + params.slug);
      return {
        slug: params.slug,
        post: post.data.result,
        categoryName: post.data.result.category.categoryName,
      };
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.readDataFromAPI(this.$route.params.slug);
  },
  head() {
    console.log('post title is : next line');
    console.log(this.post.title);
    return {
      title: this.post.title,
      meta: [
        {
          hid: "title",
          name: "title",
          content: this.post.title,
        },
        {
          hid: "apple-mobile-web-app-title",
          name: "apple-mobile-web-app-title",
          content: this.post.title,
        },
        {
          hid: "og:title",
          name: "og:title",
          content: this.post.title,
        },
        {
          hid: "description",
          name: "description",
          content: this.post.title,
        },
        {
          hid: "og:description",
          name: "og:description",
          content: this.post.title,
        },
      ],
    };
  },
```

i try get data from api in mounted and created and asyncData and fetch but not set meta tag !

Comment: change in inspect meta tag and not change in view source!!!!!!

Comment: nobody answer? "./